# CentOS web files permissions for Apache and FTP

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, permissions, ftp

I have a CentOS VPS. The problem is my html files in /var/www/html seem to need to be owned by the apache user in order for some web applications to work (ie file uploads).
If they are owned by the apache user, the web apps work but my ftp user no longer has access to the files. If they are owned by the ftp user, then the web apps stop working again.

What can I do to solve this? The only temp solution for the moment is keep them owned by the ftp user and give the directories 777 that need file uploads. I understand that this isn't secure though?

CentOS is setup with the default Apache config. FTP is proftpd and my user is in an `ftpusers` group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **groups**.

1. Add your FTP user and apache user to the same group.
2. Grant the new group enough privileges to the files/folders.
3. Change the group owner of the files/folders to be the new group.

It is recommended to change the primary group of the user using the command:

```
$ sudo usermod -g newgroup user
```

Other groups can be added using `-a -G` options. Also, the new group will not be seen in the current shell, you can to logout and login again.

Comment: I've done (1), then when I do `chown -Rf ftpuser:webfilesgroup`, the problem still exists, even with 775 on the directories. They still need 777 to be "writable" by the web app

Comment: You need to check the full path permissions not just one file/folder. Make sure your FTP user and apache user are members of your group `webfilesgroup` using the `groups` command.

Comment: They are in the group. What do you mean by full path perms? Should I set 775 on /var, /var/www, /var/www/html ?

Comment: @John: Have another look at the answer.

Comment: I added both users to the group using `-a -G`, are you saying I should  set their primary group to the `webfilesgroup`?

Comment: Yes. Also, make sure you logout and login again. Otherwise, the user groups changes will not take effect.